# How to prevent automatic truncation of leading zeros in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, zero

I have to import csv file in google spreadsheet

"Column A"
"010"
"00100"
"000100"

When I import it, I loose alle leading zero's. I know with format / numbers / notation I can create myself a fixed quantity of padding zero's but I don't want it, I want the imported spreadsheet to give, 010, 0100, 0001000.

Is there any solution for this one ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to precede your values with ' to make this work; this file imported correctly for me:

`"Column A","'010","'00100","'000100"`

Is it possible to do a find and replace on your data to add these in, so for your example find [ "] and replace it with [ "']